# How do I add a different delay in a JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

i'd like to call a function with a specific timer.
I already know about setTimeout() function, but i got a problem, here it is :

```
// mysounds is an array of audio div

mysounds .forEach(function(value, i) {
    myLoop($("#"+value+"_s")[0].duration*1000);
    // I call my function with the duration of the sample from the audio div in parameter
});

function myLoop (timer){           
    setTimeout(function (){    
        alert('hello');
    }, timer);
}
```

So, as you can see the forEach loop will be call asynchronously --> all the sounds in the array will be play at the same time and i want them to be play one after the other..

Comment: Having `$("#"+value)` is usually a strong indication you should consider learning about arrays. Moreover saving arbitrary values as properties of DOM elements may or may not work, I would definitely not count on it. Please consider learning more about clean design with separation of concerns and about having a backing view for your presentation logic and a model for your data and logic, I think it can aid you a great bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promises for this, promises represent calculating an eventual value rather than an immediate one. First, let's convert `setTimeout` to a promise:

```
function delay(ms){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function(){
        dfd.resolve();
    }, ms);

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

now, let's chain our objects. I assume you have references to them in an array:

```
var elements = [el1,el2,el3]; // elements is an array of elements, you can convert
                              // that representation you have now with a loop.

var result = delay(0); // initial value
elements.forEach(function(el){
      result = result.then(function(){ // when our current delay expires
           alert("Hello"); // element available here as `el`
           return delay(1000); // next, wait 1000 ms
      });
});
result.then(function(){
     // in here, everything is resolved.
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F3TSV/)

Comment: @FrancisDelgado glad I could help. Promises are actually quite amazing at this sort of thing and are very useful in general. You might want to read more about them as they make your life incredibly easy. As I said earlier - I really do believe `"#"+id` leads to serious lately caught bugs, I suggest arrays instead :) Happy coding and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
     var index = 0,
         timer = 1000;

     setinterval(function () {
                 alert (index)
                 index++;

               }, timer);
```

This might help you in calling your function every 1 second, but if you want to change your timing, need to clear setinterval and pass in a new timer,